# Drag and drop support

Tags: reactjs, testing, automation, playwright

Is there Drag and drop support available in Playwright codegen feature?

**Expected**
Drag and drop support in Treeview component while testing using codegen feature

**What I got**
Drag and drop feature support doesn't working in Playwright 1.38 Version.

Answer (score 0):

#### Drag and drop is not yet implemented in the codegen

As per this [ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/19892) , Drag and drop is not yet implemented in the codegen however marked as feature request by the playwright team so in the future releases , it may come as feature but at this point , it's not available.

Comment: Hi team, thanks for the update. Hope the feature comes soon